# Why do JSON APIs often return W3C datetime strings instead of UNIX epoch integers?

Tags: json, api, rest, datetime, time

To me it has always seemed simpler to represent absolute times without involving timezones. The only benefit I can think of for W3C String over Integer is the concern about 32-bits running out in the 2030's.

Comment: Because there is no defined format for dates in JSON -- it's totally up to the individual developer.  And because having a human-readable timestamp is often very helpful when trying to understand the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent in comes down to the concerns and expressivity needs of that particular API, but two qualities that are sometimes desirable are:

- Human readability
- Sometimes timezone is relevant

Expanding on the second point, consider, for example, user logs of some sort.  It's not only useful to know what "absolute" time an event may have occurred, but what the local time was for the user.  User behavior is obviously heavily influenced by time of day, so you may not want to lose that piece of information.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't thought of recording the user's timezone that way. Also if readability is the goal (which seems good to me), I wonder why I often see APIs that return UTC, instead of an offset that is closer to their expected consumers (i.e. eastern or pacific for US companies).